# Vue.js Passing Data to Another Page

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-router

I'm fetching data from REST api using `vue-resource` and showing the lists of data in the landing page. User sees the `Title` and short description, and when clicks on the `Title` user should go in that page. When I'm using `a` tag for the `URL` it's working fine, but when using `router-link` it doesn't show the `Title`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="food_list_content_bg" id="app-router">
    <div class="food_list_content">
        <h3><a href="">Article Name</a></h3>
        <router-link to="restaurant-profile.html"><h5>{{ rest.title.rendered }}</h5></router-link>
        <ul v-for="csn in rest.cuisine_type">
            <li>{{ csn.name }}</li>
        </ul>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="single_food_list_footer_top">

        <a href="">
            <ons-icon
                    icon="fa-user"
                    size="20px"
                    fixed-width="false">
            </ons-icon>
        </a>
        <div class="publisher-name">
            <strong>Added By</strong>
            <p>Board Name</p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="single_food_list_footer">
        <p>Picked For</p>
        <strong>"ITEM"</strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
(function($){
    var config = {
        api: {
            restaurants: 'data-url'
        },

    };

    var restaurants = new Vue( {
        el: '#post-list-tmpl',
        data: function() {
            return {
                restaurant: [],
                cuisin: []
            }
        },
        mounted: function () {
            this.getRestaurant();
        },
        methods: {
            getRestaurant: function () {
                var self = this;
                $.get( config.api.restaurants, function(r){
                    self.$set(self, 'restaurant', r);
                });
            }
        }
    });

    var router = new VueRouter({
        mode: 'history',
        routes: [
            { path: 'restaurent-profile.html', name: 'restaurent', component: restaurent },
        ]
    });

    new Vue({
        router,
    }).$mount('#app-router');

})( jQuery );
```

Here's [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ao45Lg0z/). How to get it work??

Also I need to pass the `id` of the clicked item to the next page `restaurant-profile.html`. Is there any way to do that ??

I'm using `Vue.js` directly including the `script`. I would prefer a way to do these without installing `Vue.js` if possible.

Comment: does restaurant-profile.html includes vue.js?

Comment: Yes, it does...

Comment: You can pass the data through the props using route.
Have a look at this [Link](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html).

Comment: Your JSFiddle is not working. You have not added any external files in fiddle.